# How to give texture to a point cloud?

Tags: c++, opencv, opengl, cuda

I have a disparity image obtained using OpenCV. I am able to display a 640 x 360 grid of points using OpenGL and CUDA, and give to each point a Z value which corresponds to the disparity value. The result:

[image: screenshot]

Now I wish to give to each point in the point cloud a colour value corresponding to the pixel in the left image of the stereo camera which have same size (640 x 380).

This is my CUDA kernel and the calling function where I have both images, the disparity and the left image (gray scale) containing the color information:

```
__global__ void simple_vbo_kernel(float4 *pos, unsigned int width, unsigned int height, float time,
        uchar* disp, int stepDisp)
{
    const int x = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    const int y = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;
     if ((x < width) && (y < height))
     {

            float u = x / (float) width;
            float v = y / (float) height;
            u = u*2.0f - 1.0f;
            v = v*2.0f - 1.0f;

            const int depth  = y * stepDisp + x;
            float w =  static_cast<float>(disp[depth]);
            w/=10;

            pos[y*width+x] = make_float4(u, w, v, 1.0f);
     }

}

extern "C"
void launch_kernel(dim3 grid, dim3 block, float4 *pos, unsigned int mesh_width,unsigned int mesh_height,
        float time, cv::Mat disp, cv::Mat left)
{
    if(!disp.empty() && !left.empty()){

        uchar* d_image;
        int dsize = disp.rows * disp.step;
        cudaMalloc((void**)&d_image, dsize);
        cudaMemcpy(d_image, disp.ptr(), dsize, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

        simple_vbo_kernel<<< grid, block>>>(pos, mesh_width, mesh_height, time, d_image, disp.step);
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        cudaFree(d_image);
    }
}
```

My question is, what is the easiest way to give a texture or colour to the points in the point cloud, in this case using the `cv::Mat left`? I have seen some other examples from the CUDA samples but I did not find how to do it.

Comment: … or just wait for someone with edit-rights to insert the inline picture.

Comment: since each point corresponds to a single pixel there seems to be no need to assign a texture to it but you want to give it a single color (of the corresp. pixel)?!? atm you render each point green

Comment: I render each point green by using this function:     glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0); Just to have a green color instead of the default white. But my purpose is to give the color information of a gray scale image or a color image to each pixel of the 3D image since both image in 2D have the same pixel size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. In the kernel part I have a new uchar4 mapped input for the color, both input pointers must have same size for a correct relation between point and color (float4 *pos and uchar4 *color). Since d_image is a gray scale image (disparity image) and the one to give texture is a color image, this should be taken into account for the way to access to each array. Opencv it is in BGR order and gstreamer in RGB:

```
__global__ void simple_vbo_kernel(float4 *pos, uchar4 *color, unsigned int width, unsigned int height, uchar* d_image, int stepDisp, uchar* d_color, int stepLeft)
{
    const int x = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    const int y = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;
     if ((x < width) && (y < height)){

            float u = x / (float) width;
            float v = y / (float) height;
            u = u*2.0f - 1.0f;
            v = v*2.0f - 1.0f;

            const int depthi  = y * stepDisp + x;
            float w =  static_cast<float>(d_image[depthi]);
            w/=25;
            pos[y*width+x] = make_float4(u, w, v, 1.0f);

            uchar b =  static_cast<uchar>(d_color[y*width*3+x*3 + 0]);
            uchar g =  static_cast<uchar>(d_color[y*width*3+x*3 + 1]);
            uchar r =  static_cast<uchar>(d_color[y*width*3+x*3 + 2]);
            color[y*width+x] = make_uchar4( r, g, b, 1.0f);
     }

}

extern "C"
void launch_kernel(dim3 grid, dim3 block, unsigned int mesh_width, unsigned int mesh_height, float4 *pos,  cv::Mat disp, uchar4 *color,  cv::Mat left)
{
    if(!disp.empty() && !left.empty()){

        uchar* d_image;
        int dsize = disp.rows * disp.step;
        cudaMalloc((void**)&d_image, dsize);
        cudaMemcpy(d_image, disp.ptr(), dsize, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

        uchar* d_color;
        int dcolorsize = left.rows * left.step;
        cudaMalloc((void**)&d_color, dcolorsize);
        cudaMemcpy(d_color, left.ptr(), dcolorsize, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    simple_vbo_kernel<<< grid, block>>>(pos, color, mesh_width, mesh_height, d_image, disp.step, d_color, left.step);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    cudaFree(d_image);
    cudaFree(d_color);

    }
}
```

Calling to the kernel:

```
void runCuda(struct cudaGraphicsResource **vbo_resource, Mat dsp, struct cudaGraphicsResource **vbo_resource_color, Mat lft)
{
    float4 *dptr_pos;
    checkCudaErrors(cudaGraphicsMapResources(1, vbo_resource, 0));
    size_t num_bytes;
    checkCudaErrors(cudaGraphicsResourceGetMappedPointer((void **)&dptr_pos, &num_bytes, *vbo_resource));

    uchar4 *dptr_color;
    checkCudaErrors(cudaGraphicsMapResources(1, vbo_resource_color, 0));
    size_t num_bytes_color;
    checkCudaErrors(cudaGraphicsResourceGetMappedPointer((void **)&dptr_color, &num_bytes_color, *vbo_resource_color));

    dim3 block(8, 8, 1);
    dim3 grid(mesh_width / block.x, mesh_height / block.y, 1);
    launch_kernel(grid,block, mesh_width, mesh_height, dptr_pos, dsp, dptr_color, lft);

    checkCudaErrors(cudaGraphicsUnmapResources(1, vbo_resource, 0));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaGraphicsUnmapResources(1, vbo_resource_color, 0));
}
```

Also important in the initialization of the OpenGl add this:

```
glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );
```

and  also enable depth test. I had Disabled before and I have strange image overlapings:

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

And the part where the image must be shown or updated, in my case I have it in my `glutDisplayFunc(display)` function:

```
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, pos_vbo);
    glVertexPointer(4, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, color_vbo);
    glColorPointer(4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, 0);
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

    glPointSize(3.0);
    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, mesh_width * mesh_height);

    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    glutSwapBuffers();
    glFlush();
    glDeleteTextures(1, &color_vbo);
```

My image is a grayscale image because I am still trying to capture my rtsp stream with gstreamer 0.10 in color
http://postimg.org/image/ub8ds4zw5/

I have opened a new post trying to solve the color issue:

[GstBuffer to color Mat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30248753/gstbuffer-to-color-mat)

Answer (score 4):

In case of sparse point clouds (like your's) usually the best course of action is adding a colour attribute to the vertices and assign it the desired color. Make the drawing shaders pass the value of that attribute to the emited fragment color.

Comment: Should be like that. I know how to acces to the color information in my left Mat image inside the kernel (very similar to what I have done with the disparity Mat image), but I still do not know how to add an extra colour attribute to my pixels. If you can show an example I will be grateful.

Comment: With your advice I am finding some good tutorials I will try a solution. Thank you.